# Convert GeoTIFF to KMZ

Tags: python, pyqgis, gdal, geotiff-tiff

I am trying to convert a GeoTIFF to a KMZ. Here's my code:

```py
from osgeo import gdal
import zipfile

srcf = r"C:\raster_to_kml\OrthoImage.tif"
vfn = "/vsimem/OrthoImage.jpg"
drv = gdal.GetDriverByName('JPEG')
src = gdal.Open(srcf)
tgt = drv.CreateCopy(vfn,src)
rasterLyr = QgsRasterLayer(srcf,"OrthoImage")
e = rasterLyr.extent()

kml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
    <Document>
        <name>Valleyfield</name>
        <GroundOverlay>
            <name>Image</name>
            <drawOrder>30</drawOrder>
            <Icon>
             <href>OrthoImage.jpg</href>
            </Icon>
            <LatLonBox>
              <north>%s</north>
              <south>%s</south>
              <east>%s</east>
              <west>%s<west>
            </LatLonBox>
        </GroundOverlay>
    </Document>
</kml>""" %(e.yMaximum(),e.yMinimum(), e.xMaximum(), e.xMinimum()) 

vsifile = gdal.VSIFOpenL(vfn,'r')
gdal.VSIFSeekL(vsifile, 0, 2)
vsileng = gdal.VSIFTellL (vsifile)
gdal.VSIFSeekL(vsifile, 0, 0)
z = zipfile.ZipFile(r"C:\raster_to_kml\OrthoImage.kmz", "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
z.writestr("doc.kml", kml)
z.writestr("OrthoImage.jpg", gdal.VSIFReadL(1, vsileng, vsifile))
z.close()
```

I use QGIS 3.0
Here's the error message i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 38, in <module>
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\zipfile.py", line 1760, in writestr
    zinfo.file_size = len(data)            # Uncompressed size
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Comment: Have you tried printing all of your file objects to make sure they're getting created correctly? `NoneType` suggests that one of them isn't getting created, causing the error.

Comment: The problem here is in the zipfile.py lib, perhaps it would be better to ask this question on Stack Overflow https://stackoverflow.com as it relates more to general computing than to geographic data.